# Filling arrays equally

Tags: javascript, arrays

given 2 arrays (with max length of lets say 15):

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var data = [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
```

what would be the best approach to "fill" arrays `a` and `b` equally with the data from `data` array, so they both be the same length (or as close to it) but not exceed max length?

required result *could* look like this:

```
var a = [1,2,3,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
var b = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,22,23,24,25,26];
```

---

*my situation is more complex, and I'm looking for an efficient way: I have 2 sides on the screen, each side might have profile photos of ppl from FB. if there aren't enough photos in one side, I need to add "fake" photos to fill it, so both sides will look more or less evenly filled with photos*

Comment: `(a.length + b.length + data.length)/2`, and then loop.  Why not tell us more about your complex situation?

Comment: @Brad - loop? what would be the logic which would decide where goes what?

Comment: I'd use slice instead of a loop

Comment: @BeNdErR - now there's a good conversation going on here. could please you elaborate on how would the slice method works in this situation?

Comment: I would count how many elements I need to add to the first one, let's say *n*, then slice the data array from index *0* to *n* and push the values into array a, the remaining items from *n+1* to *data.lenght* will be added to array b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a    = [1,2,3];
var b    = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var data = [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

for( var i = data.length; i--; ){
  if (a.length > b.length)
      b.push(data[i])
  else
      a.push(data[i])
}

console.log(a.length, b.length);
```

Comment: this is great. simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without having to loop through the elements:

```
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    data = [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

var targetLength = (a.length + b.length + data.length)/2,
    aCnt = Math.ceil(targetLength) - a.length,
    bCnt = Math.floor(targetLength) - b.length;

a = a.concat(data.slice(0, aCnt));
b = b.concat(data.slice(aCnt, data.length));

// a is [1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
// b is [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

Comment: you also have to check if a.lenght > b.lenght or a.lenght < b.lenght

Comment: this answer looks most promising, but as I understand OP, `targetLength` can be arbitrary and `data` can have many many more elements than needed..

Comment: @BeNdErR no, you don't in this algorithm.

Comment: you don't need the `data.length` at the end. omitting that would just mean slice the array to it's end.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Brad's comment, I imagine you could do something like this:

```
ab=[];
ab=ab.concat(a,b,data);
del = (a.length + b.length + data.length) / 2;
a = [];
b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(del); i++) {
    a.push(ab[i]);
    b.push(ab[Math.ceil(del) + i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm would be like:

1) Identify the number of elements in `a`

2) Identify the number of elements in `b`

3) Identify the number of elements in `data`

4) if elements in `a` is less than `b`, then populate a from `data` till it becomes equal to `b` or vice versa

5) if in both `a` and `b` elements are equal, and `data` still having the elements, then populate the array `a` and `b` alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

you want to the last index of a and b have 12 deference and len of final array is 12!!! i think u can use this algorithm !
:

```
for j in data:
  while ( j-max(a)) == 12 ):
   x++
for i in range(x):
 data[i]=a[i]
```

and after this delete the indexes with index number mor than 12 !

Answer (score 0):

my solution was this:

```
var a    = [1,2,3];
var b    = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var data = [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

var howManyToFill = (data.length + (b.length + a.length)/2)/2;
// take half of the "data" and put it in "a"
a = a.concat(data.slice(0,howManyToFill));
// what's left goes to "b"
b = b.concat(data.slice(howManyToFill));

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: The extra concat and the splices are expensive operations. Not sure if performance was a concern, but your solution is 80% slower than the one I posted (see http://jsperf.com/splitting-arrays).

Comment: you're right. I'll get rid of the first concat, it's unnecessary

Comment: answer has been updated to use `slice` which is faster than `splice`

Comment: So why didn't you just accept my answer as correct since it is basically identical to what you ended up with? That's kind of how StackOverflow works - ask a question, get some help, accept the one that works for you.

Comment: @Bill - I don't have to accept any answer right away, I was waiting for more answers. in the best I didn't accept your answer, because Indra's answer was better in my opinion. it's readable, which is the most important thing, and it is performant. wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = [1,2,3];
var a = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var data = [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

// find how many more elements need to be added to the smaller array 
var diff = Math.abs(b.length - a.length);

// get the elements to add to the smallest array
var data1 = data.splice(0, diff + ((data.length - diff) / 2));

// data now only contains the elements that will not be added to the smallest array

if (a.length < b.length) {
    // a is the smallest array
    a.push.apply(a,  data1);
    b.push.apply(b, data);
} else {
    // b is the smallest array
    b.push.apply(b,  data1);
    a.push.apply(a, data);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you agree that this technique is far more complicated than the other answers here?